# how to save the state of radio button?

Tags: swift, userdefaults, dlradiobutton

i am trying to save the state of my radio button but it doesn't working for me any idea how to do that? i am using userdefaults for that now

```
class WTSettingsVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn: DLRadioButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn2: DLRadioButton!
    var switchON : Bool = false
    var button : Bool = false
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkBttn.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")
        checkBttn2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super .viewWillAppear(animated)
         self.setCommonNavigationBar(title: "Settings", largeTitle: true, tranpernt: false, tint: WTConstant.LMColors.greenTheme, fontColor: .white)
        checkBttn?.isEnabled =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
        checkBttn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bttnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func bttnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1  {
           sender.isEnabled = true
             switchON = true
             defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switchON")


        }else if sender.tag == 2{
            sender.isEnabled = true
            switchON = false
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switchON")


                }
            }
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isEnabled, forKey: "switchState")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }

}
```

Comment: There are 3 different keys being used for `UserDefaults` and not consistently. And you are trying to use the same key for two different buttons. And don't use `synchronize()`, it's deprecated.

Comment: Why are you using the same key for storing the state of 2 different buttons ?

Comment: i am just new at this so can you please tell me how to do this.  i will be grateful to take your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same key to store state of two buttons. And use same key for storing and retrieving the state of a button.

```
class WTSettingsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn: DLRadioButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn2: DLRadioButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkBttn.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "checkBttnSelected")
        checkBttn2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "checkBttn2Selected")
        checkBttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bttnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        checkBttn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bttnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func bttnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
        if sender == checkBttn  {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "checkBttnSelected")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "checkBttn2Selected")
        }else if sender == checkBttn2 {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "checkBttnSelected")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "checkBttn2Selected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code is pretty obviously nested improperly. For example, the following code isn't actually executing in the bttnAction function:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isEnabled, forKey: "switchState")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

This code needs to be placed within the curly bracket above it. Try rewriting your code similarly to this:

```
class WTSettingsVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn: DLRadioButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBttn2: DLRadioButton!
    var switchON : Bool = false
    var button : Bool = false
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        checkBttn.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")
        checkBttn2.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "issaved")

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setCommonNavigationBar(title: "Settings", largeTitle: true, tranpernt: false, tint: WTConstant.LMColors.greenTheme, fontColor: .white)
        checkBttn?.isEnabled =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
        checkBttn?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bttnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func bttnAction(_ sender: DLRadioButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            sender.isEnabled = true
            switchON = true
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switchON")


        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            sender.isEnabled = true
            switchON = false
            defaults.set(switchON, forKey: "switchON")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isEnabled, forKey: "switchState")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Because these lines of code were outside of the closing bracket for that function, the lines weren't actually included in any function and, thus, would never be called.